# which way is better to access sql server by ip or local server name

Tags: sql-server

i using Sql server 2012 Express and i have't a managed server.For security purpose i want to use sql connection by local instance name.so what the better to access the server by ip or local instance name if server and application are on same server machine?

Comment: I would always avoid using IP because that could change easy, unless you are using 127.0.0.1

Comment: @GuidoG even then I would say use (local) instead of the IP address.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes even then I agree.And you could also end up on a machine with only ip6 enabled, I guess that 127.0.0.1 would be invalid then